# Как работает sleep()?

Tags: sleep

По идее, во время бездействия процессор не делает ничего. Но как обеспечиваются временные задержки в программах? Читал в разных источниках, что в программах на DOS задержки производились с помощью циклов - как результат, нагрузка процессора. `Sleep()` же практически не нагружает его. Каким образом это достигается?

Иначе говоря, как работает процессор во время простоя?

Comment: "практически не нагружает его" а вы где смотрели нагрузку?

Comment: @D-side, `ps -A` - процессорное время и `htop` - нагрузка на ядра.

Comment: да просто процессу времени не дают и всё.

Comment: @Croessmah, тогда такой вопрос - что делает процессор во время простоя?

Comment: Выполняет другие процессы.

Comment: @kff, всё равно не понимаю. Почему тогда нагрузка во время простоя не превышает 10%?

Comment: @Андрей в системе много других задач. Но если уж так случилось, что процессору (ядру) нечем заняться, то он либо засыпает, либо выполняет циклы холостого хода.

Comment: @Croessmah, это циклы с `nop`?

Comment: http://www.cyberforum.ru/blogs/18334/blog4913.html и вторую часть статьи тоже читать. Третья пока не готова, увы.

Comment: @Croessmah, большое спасибо! Если есть желание - оформите, как ответ.

Comment: А вы обращали внимание, что в старых windows в диспетчере задач причутствовало "бездействие системы", которое потребляло остатки процессора. Оно есть всегда, а вот показывают его или нет, это уже второй вопрос. И кстати, кроме nop, есть еще hlt, которое фактически выключает ядро до возникновения прерывания

Comment: @Mike, да, наблюдался такой "процесс". Меня тогда удивляло, почему же, грубо говоря, процессор не греется.

Comment: Ну вот потому и не грелся, что фактически это был цикл из HLT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**На самом деле, процессор всё время чем-то занимается.**

---

DOS – однозадачная система. Она не занимается распределением ресурсов между процессами с целью обеспечить им более-менее параллельную работу. Поэтому когда внутри выполняемого в заданный момент процесса делать особенно нечего, ему остаётся только заниматься чем-нибудь бесполезным. Ведь процессор принадлежит ему практически безраздельно.

---

В многозадачных же системах, вроде Linux, в системе обычно выполняется много процессов, и ядро распределяет доступное время между ними. Но не всегда процессы и ядро забирают всё. Бывает, остаётся время, в которое нечем заняться. Это оставшееся время выдаётся "процессу бездействия". А он не считается полезной нагрузкой.

Системный вызов `sleep` отдаёт ядру команду "разбуди меня, когда настанет время Х", после чего отдаёт управление ядру. Ядро может что-то сделать само, может отдать управление очередному процессу, а если делать нечего, отдаст кусочек времени на "бездействие".

Как именно реализован и что делает "процесс бездействия" зависит от архитектуры процессора (есть ли у него специальные возможности по бездействию) и реализации в ОС (теоретически можно особыми возможностями процессора не пользоваться, но это обычно нерационально).

---

"Процент нагрузки" это скорее условный подсчёт со стороны ОС "сколько времени процессор занимался чем-нибудь содержательным".

Comment: Мне как то первое утверждение режет глаз. Если делать абсолютно нечего нормальная ОС дает HLT. Хотя конечно его можно воспринимать как очень долго выполняющуюся инструкцию

Comment: @Mike важно различать "нечего делать **сейчас**" и "нечего делать **вообще**".

Comment: @Mike а, понял о чём вы. Ну, да, я в этом контексте его рассматриваю как долгую инструкцию, выданную процессом бездействия. Но могут быть и другие реализации.

Comment: Кстати, глянул исходники linux. Как я и подозревал hlt уже не в моде... Сейчас процессор гасят функциями ACPI, которые действуют со стороны логики материнской платы, переводя процессор физически в одно из нерабочих, но "горячих" состояний, из которых его можно будет вывести не выполняя полного reset

Comment: А что скажете насчёт программ-демонов с вечным циклом? Корректно же ставить внутри цикла `usleep()`, чтобы не грузить процессор лишний раз?

Comment: @Андрей такие программы обычно ждут чего-то более вещественного, например активности в IO. Для таких задач sleep скорее вреден, т. к. увеличит задержку срабатывания (процесс может висеть на таймере, когда для него пришли данные в IO, которые он запросит сразу после таймера). Для программ же, которые делают что-то каждый период времени, sleep нужен практически по определению.

Comment: @D-side, просто прикидываю, как бы правильно организовать БД. Сейчас пришёл к мнению, что относительно небольшую и часто используемую базу можно держать в ОЗУ, периодически скидывая изменения на диск. Но для того, чтоб держать её в памяти, нужен фоновый процесс.

Comment: @Андрей БД обычно ожидает команды извне, в этой ситуации sleep не нужен, достаточно сделать синхронное чтение следующей команды и ОС и так остановит процесс, пока что-нибудь не поступит.

Comment: @D-side, думал сделать с помощью сигналов, но пока что ничего.

Comment: @Андрей я знаю одно исключение, ScyllaDB. Которая не полагается на синхронный возврат IO из ОС и вместо этого опрашивает IO сама, асинхронно, якобы так задержки при полной загрузке ниже. На мой взгляд это сомнительное решение, задержки такой природы уже стоит чинить с помощью ядра ОС (использовать и улучшать реалтаймовое ядро, к примеру). Но это моё мнение, подкреплённое только интуицией.

Comment: @Андрей БД же будет общаться с внешним миром, данные передавать, значит скорее всего будет использовать сокеты. Так и спите себе спокойно на сокетах функциями вроде select() с таймаутом, по таймауту собственно периодические операции и выполняйте

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за подсказку :)